# Probability of reaching state $b$ before $-a$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, random-walk

We define the lazy random walk $S_n$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ which goes left with probability $\frac{1}{2}$, right with probability $\frac{1}{4}$, and stay in place with probability $\frac{1}{4}$. Assume that $S_0=0$ and $a,b \ge 1$ integers. Find the probability that $S_n$ hits $b$ before reaching $-a$.

I was thinking about applying the Doob's optional stopping theorem but can' figure out how. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way 1: define a time $\tau$ to hit the boundary, define $u(n)=P(S_\tau=b)$, define a recurrence relation for $u$ using the total probability formula, solve the resulting equation for all $u(n)$, plug in $n=0$. The setup of the recursion is $u(n)=(1/2) u(n+1) + (1/4) u(n) + (1/4) u(n-1)$ and then the boundary conditions are $u(b)=1,u(-a)=0$. This recurrence can be solved.

Way 2: define a time $\tau$ to hit the boundary, prove it satisfies one of the possible conditions of the optional stopping theorem. Then consider the martingale $M_n=S_n-n/4$. On the one hand $E[M_\tau]=E[M_0]$ while on the other hand $E[M_\tau]=b P(S_\tau=b) + (-a) P(S_\tau=-a)-E[\tau]/4$. Thus you can obtain the desired probability provided that you know $E[\tau]$; one way to get $E[\tau]$ is to follow a procedure very similar to Way 1.

Comment: Yes I understand this approach but I am unable to show that $E(\tau) < \infty$

Comment: @MathsFreak You can use the characterization via $t \wedge \tau$ (see Wikipedia), or you can go through and show the expectation is finite (the method that I know for that uses a method very similar to Way 1). It's not a.s. bounded, so you're not going to be able to prove that it is.

Comment: Okay, so if $S_n$ is a martingale, I know that $E[S_{\tau  \wedge t}]=E[S_{\tau \wedge 0}]=E(S_0)=0$. Will that work?

Comment: My bad, $S_n$ is a supermartingale thus $E[S_{T \wedge t}] < E[S_0]$

Comment: @MathsFreak It's a martingale (the increments have zero expectation).

Comment: Oh yes. So, I think we can now use the optional stopping theorem right?

Comment: @MathsFreak Yes.

Comment: I think it is not correct that the increments have $0$ expectation. It is a random walk biased to the left! So, it should be a super-martingale

Comment: @MathsFreak My bad, I misread and thought the 1/2 was the laziness probability. You can subtract off the mean to get a martingale but then you will need to find $E[\tau]$ to finish the problem, so I think it is easier to just use a recursion to begin with.

Comment: I am not really sure how to use the recursion. Can you elucidate?

Comment: @MathsFreak Does this help?

Comment: I get the idea! But will it not be $u(n) = \frac{1}{4} u(n-1) + \frac{1}{4}u(n) + \frac{1}{2} u(n+1)$?

Comment: @MathsFreak Yes, my bad again.

Comment: Ok, so if I solve the recursion, I have $u(n) = \frac{2^a -1}{(2^a - 2^{-b})2^n}$. Plugging in $n=0$, it becomes $\frac{2^a -1}{(2^a - 2^{-b})}$. So, is this our required probability? Can you confirm whether this is true?

Comment: @MathsFreak Maybe you mixed up which of $a$ and $b$ has the minus sign somewhere? Your $u(b)$ is in general not $1$. The solution for $u(n)$ should be of the form $c_1 + c_2 2^{-n}$ and $c_1$ will not be zero since there is no $n$ such that $1=2^n \cdot 0$.

Comment: I think $c_1$ comes out to be $\frac{2^a}{2^a - 2^{-b}}$ and $c_2$ comes out to be $\frac{-1}{2^a - 2^{-b}}$

Comment: @MathsFreak Then you have $\frac{2^a-2^b}{2^a-2^{-b}} \neq 1$. The system you're solving for the coefficients is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2^{-a} \\ 1 & 2^b \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, maybe that will help you finish.

Comment: Ah, yes! I sort of mixed up $b$ and $-a$. Can you elaborate on why should we plug in $n=0$ into $u(n)$ to get the probability of reaching $b$ before $-a$?

Comment: @MathsFreak It is a combination of the total probability formula and the Markov property: $P(S_\tau=b \mid S_0=x)=\sum_{i=-1}^1 P(S_\tau=b \mid S_1=x+i) P(S_1=x+i \mid S_0=x)$, and then $P(S_\tau=b \mid S_1=x+i)=u(x+i)$ by the Markov property. Then the boundary conditions are basically saying that if you start at $b$ or $-a$ then the process ends immediately, with "success" or "failure" respectively.